# Tensorboard not working with Keras-rl, why?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0, tensorboard, keras-rl

When I want to execute Tensorboard with keras-rl (DQNAgent):

```
tb_callback = TensorBoard('/home/jose/TED/MLU_minimization/logs', update_freq=1)
dqn.fit(env, nb_steps=5000000, visualize=False, verbose=1, nb_max_episode_steps=None, log_interval=10000, callbacks=[tb_callback])
```

I obtain the next error:

> AttributeError: 'TensorBoard' object has no attribute '_should_trace'. Did you mean: '_stop_trace'?

After the next:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "/home/jose/TED/MLU_minimization/DRL.py", line 303, in 
> dqn.fit(env, nb_steps=5000000, visualize=False, verbose=1, nb_max_episode_steps=None, log_interval=10000, callbacks=[tb_callback])
> File "/home/jose/TED/MLU_minimization/envDRL/lib/python3.10/site-packages/rl/core.py", line 100, in fit
> callbacks = CallbackList(callbacks)
> File "/home/jose/TED/MLU_minimization/envDRL/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/callbacks.py", line 239, in **init**
> self._batch_hooks_support_tf_logs = all(
> File "/home/jose/TED/MLU_minimization/envDRL/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/callbacks.py", line 242, in 
> if cb._implements_train_batch_hooks() or cb
> File "/home/jose/TED/MLU_minimization/envDRL/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/callbacks.py", line 2770, in _implements_train_batch_hooks
> return self._should_trace or self.write_steps_per_second

Comment: The error you're facing  seems to be due to a conflict between the TensorBoard callback provided by Keras and TensorFlow. It appears that there might be a naming clash or some compatibility issue between the versions of Keras and TensorFlow you are using. Ensure that the versions of Keras and TensorFlow you are using are compatible with each other.Instead of using the TensorBoard callback from Keras, you can create a custom callback that uses TensorFlow's tf.summary API directly to log the necessary data for TensorBoard.